# CakePdf para o CakePHP 3.x, DUVIDA!

Tags: php, html, cakephp, composer

Estou utilizando o CakePdf, pro cake 3.x

Segue o link : https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf/tree/3.0

Estou tendo problemas, pois eu fiz de acordo com o próprio.. e quando digito .pdf.. fica do msm jeito.

Ex:
http://localhost/segundo_seti/invoices/view/1.pdf

Resumindo, não apresenta erro, não fica no formato de pdf, fica do mesmo jeito da view normal.

Queria saber se alguém sabe o porquê disso.

Comment: Já viu se há algo gravado no LOG, mesmo que não seja erro? Como está o seu código?